# Tables don't show up under newly created .mdf in VS Express 2012 for Web

Tags: sql-server, database, visual-studio-express

Just trying to get my feet wet and starting with what ought to be a simple database web app. Here are the steps I've taken to start the project. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

1. New Project
2. Visual Basic > ASP.NET Empty Web Application
3. Right-click newly created solution > Add > Add ASP.NET Folder > App_Data
4. Right-click newly created App_Data folder > Add > New Item > SQL Server Database (under Visual Basic > Data)
5. Select Database Explorer (Ctrl + Alt + S) and expand Data Connections
6. Right-click newly created .mdf > Refresh
7. Expand .mdf, right-click Tables > Add New Table
8. Create table schema
9. Save table as .sql file

And that's where I hit a wall. The next step is to create another table for a relational database, but it doesn't matter how many tables I create - none of them ever appear under the Tables folder in Database Explorer. Consequently I cannot proceed.

Comment: I see that the question has received 11 views, but no responses yet. Please let me know if I can provide more information to make a response more likely. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There is an update button top of the table you can click then it saved it on the existing mdf file, under the table there is a sql query on that you can edit your table in inside [table]. that means replace the name table. to see the change or whether your table is created or not you have to rightclick the table folder on the database connection and refresh.